# Dice Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If I have 4 dices (1-6) how many possibilities do I have to get exactly one 2?
So for example a combination of 2, 3, 2, 4 is not possible.

My solution was: 4 * 5^3.

Thx :D

Comment: Yes, that works.  For posting with mathematical expressions, see [this introduction](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dice are of different colors, first one picks the location of the $2$ (in 4 ways) and then fills the other 3 outcomes with any non-2 values, so your solution is correct:
$$
4 \times 5^3 = 500.
$$

If the dice are identical, you have to account for the fact that the above argument counts e.g. 2,4,3,4 and 2,3,4,4 twice, when it is in reality one combination.